# Is the adamic alphabet the origin of the Greek?

Tags: language, greek

The [adamic alphabet](http://nupedia.wikia.com/wiki/Adamic_alphabet) seems to cover the entire Greek alphabet including even more letters and symbols, like *sampi*, *heta* (which I thought was just the origin of *eta*, but apparently not), *yot*, *koppa* etc... From the source:

> Adamic alphabet is world's first vowel+consonant phoneme-level script, invented as such by the Greeks, which features both vowels and consonants on equal level, which as such is most suitable for writing world's first human language, known as Adamic tongue. Adamic alphabet is also used for Adamic digit system.

I have found [another source here](http://www.ancientscripts.com/greek.html) that seems to have studies the background of the Greek alphabet in detail. There is no mention of the adamic alphabet, and their description of the origin is different:

> The Greeks were the first Europeans to learn to write with an alphabet, and from them alphabetic writing spread to the rest of Europe, eventually leading down to all modern European alphabets. Incidentally, the Greeks tried writing once before. Between 1500 and 1200 BCE, the Mycenaeans, an early tribe of Greeks, adapted **the Minoan syllabary as Linear B to write an early form of Greek**. However, the syllabary was not well suited to write Greek, and the exact pronunciation of Mycenaean words remains somewhat obcure. The alphabet, on the other hand, allowed a more precise record of the sounds in the language.
>
> From the shape of the letters, it is clear that **the Greeks adopted the alphabet the Phoenician script**, mostly like during the late 9th century BCE. In fact, Greek historian Herotodus, who lived during the 5th century BCE, called the Greek letters "phoinikeia grammata" (φοινικήια γράμματα), which means Phoenician letters.

Is the adamic alphabet simply an even earlier precessor to the Greek alphabet?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I am certain that people were speaking Greek for a long time before the development of the Greek alphabet. Are you asking if the Greek alphabet was influences by the Adamic alphabet?

Comment: @axsvl77 I see. I've edited it to be more precisely about the alphabet only. I am curious as to if the adamic alphabet is just an ancient version of the Greek alphabet as we know it?

Comment: It seems it is some religious site, it claims the first human language spoken by Adam was the direct predecessor of Zend (Indo-European), which is contrary to modern science.

Comment: It reflects the views of Anne Catherine Emmerich, a 18-19 century Catholic saint who claimed that Hebrew was not the language of Adam, but an Indo-Iranian language was because it had similarity to German.

Comment: @Anixx - While searching, I found some references to this being a 13th Century Medieval belief, relating to early linguistic philosophical thought that there had to be a first language (and obviously that would be the one the first humans, Adam and Eve, used to communicate). However, the website that was on was also IMHO not very credible.

Comment: That alphabet isn't even logically consistent. Check out how badly "theta" is spelled, for instance. For digamma. It doesn't even make sense. Someone made that without actually knowing Greek. It's pure 100% made up fantasy.

Comment: Adamic alphabet? This is the history site. Maybe you should try SF&F.

Answer (score 34):

That particular website, well ... its not very credible. Its part of [Wikia](http://www.wikia.com/fandom), a site designed for Science Fiction/Fantasy fans to create their own wikis. In other words, things don't get deleted/removed/edited out there just because they have no relation whatsoever to reality. This person's Wikia site reuses the name of the [defunct precursor to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nupedia), which I find highly dishonest and misleading.

Outside of that website, I could find one other decent reference to this supposed Alphabet: from a Mormon website.<sup>*</sup> It claims this is the alphabet used by the speakers of "Adamic", supposedly the world's first language, spoken by *Adam* and Eve, and also currently spoken in Heaven. In other words, **this is somebody's religious belief**.

**The current scholarly consensus is that the Greek Alphabet is was copied from the [Phoenician Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet#History)**. Technically this was an [Abjad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad#Origins), not an Alphabet, as Semitic languages have predictable vowels, and thus don't usually need to bother representing them in their writing. Indo-European languages like Greek don't have that feature, so the Greeks had to re-purpose some unneeded Phoenician consonants to indicate vowels. This is how the Greeks managed to get credit for the first Alphabet, even though all they really did was hack an existing Abjad to work for their language.

Here's a comparison chart of the two Alphabets, taken from the [Greek Alphabet Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Origins) page just now.

[image]

<sup>* -  Not linked, as I don't believe it deserves the page-rank bump.</sup>